# How to pass (space) as value to api in case the value is empty

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an update profile API, where first name, last name are one of the parameters. I have separated the name into two strings with space as delimiter. But in case if the user doesn't give last name and update, the page crashes saying "ArrayIndex Out of Bounds Exception". I tried putting an if condition to pass last name value as "space" incase last name is empty. But it doesn't work. Please help to validate this condition and pass value accordingly. Attached the specific piece of code below:

Code

```
private void updateprofile() {
            firstname = edtName.getText().toString();
            lastname = edtName.getText().toString();
            splitstring = txtName.split(" ");
            firstname = splitstring[0].trim();
            lastname = splitstring[1].trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(lastname))
            {
                lastname=" ";
            }
    else
            {
                lastname = splitstring[1].trim();

            }
            Call<UpdateProfile> call = apiService.updateprofile(userId, firstname, lastname, profileurl, location, email, mobilenumber);

            Log.e("DATA PASSED", userId + " " + firstname + " " + lastname + " " + profileurl + " " + location + email + mobilenumber);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateProfile>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UpdateProfile> call, Response<UpdateProfile> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String status = response.body().getStatus();
                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mainActivity.imgHomeMenu.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit_icon);
                            flagoption = true;
                            imgEditPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mainActivity.txvTitle.setText("PROFILE");
                            edtName.setEnabled(false);
                            edtLocation.setEnabled(false);
                            edtEmail.setEnabled(false);
                            edtPhone.setEnabled(false);
                            linearEmail.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_profile_changes_two));

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UpdateProfile> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Profile View:

```
private void callProfileApi(Context context) {
        vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

        Call<ProfileDetails> call = apiService.callProfile(userId);
        Log.e("USER ID INSIDE API", userId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfileDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProfileDetails> call, Response<ProfileDetails> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ProfileDetails resp = response.body();
                    if (resp != null) {
                        String status = resp.getStatus();

                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

                            profileurl = resp.getUserDetail().getImage();
                            txtName = resp.getUserDetail().getName();
                            String joineddate = resp.getUserDetail().getJoined();
                            String[] join = joineddate.split(" ");
                            Log.e("join", join[0]);
                            splitstring = txtName.split(" ");
                            firstname = splitstring[0].trim();
                            lastname = splitstring[1].trim();
/*
                            if(edtName.getText().toString().trim().contains(" ")){
                                splitstring = txtName.split(" ");
                                firstname = splitstring[0].trim();
                                lastname = splitstring[1].trim();
                            }else{
                                lastname=" ";
                                Log.e("Name Error","Enter Name");
                            }*/
                            //txtjoinedDate = GlobalMethods.Date(join[0]);
                            txtjoinedDate = resp.getUserDetail().getJoined();
                            rating = resp.getUserDetail().getRating();
                            location = resp.getUserDetail().getLocation();
                            email = resp.getUserDetail().getEmail();
                            mobilenumber = resp.getUserDetail().getMobile();
                            ratingbar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating));

                            emailverification = resp.getUserDetail().getEmailVerification();
                            if (emailverification.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                txtEmail.setText("Verify");
                                txtEmail.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_profile_changes_three));
                            } else {
                                txtEmail.setText("Verified");
                                txtEmail.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_profile_changes_two));

                            }
                            mobileverfication = resp.getUserDetail().getMobileVerification();
                            if (mobileverfication.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                txtPhone.setText("Verify");
                                txtPhone.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_profile_changes_three));
                            } else {
                                txtPhone.setText("Verified");
                                txtPhone.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_background_profile_changes_two));

                            }

                            vehicleList = resp.getVehicles();
                            if (vehicleList.size() > 0) {
                                myVehicleAdapter = new MyVehicleProfileAdapter(getActivity(), vehicleList, "3");
                                recycleVehicleRegister.setAdapter(myVehicleAdapter);
                                recycleVehicleRegister.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));


                            } else {
                                recycleVehicleRegister.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                txtNovehicles.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                vehiclelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                            reviewList = resp.getReviews();
                            if (reviewList.size() > 0) {
                                profileReviewsAdapter = new ProfileReviewsAdapter(getContext(), reviewList);
                                recycleViewfeedback.setAdapter(profileReviewsAdapter);
                                recycleViewfeedback.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                            } else {
                                recycleViewfeedback.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                txtNoreviews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                morereviewslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                /*morereviewslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                recycleViewfeedback.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                notfoundlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
                            }


                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(profileurl)) {
                                userProfiPlaceholder.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_placeholder));
                                Glide.with(getContext()).load(profileurl).into(userProfiPlaceholder);
                                edtName.setText(txtName);
                                Log.e("PROFILE NAME", txtName);


                                ratingbar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating));
                                txtRateText.setText(rating);
                                txtBalance.setText("$"+resp.getUserDetail().getReferralBalance());
                                edtLocation.setText(location);
                                edtEmail.setText(email);
                                edtPhone.setText(mobilenumber);
                                edtId.setText(idproof);
                            } else {

                                Glide.with(getContext()).load(profileurl).into(userProfiPlaceholder);
                                edtName.setText(txtName);
                                Log.e("PROFILE NAME", txtName);
                                txtJoinedDate.setText("Joined" + " " + txtjoinedDate);

                                ratingbar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating));
                                txtRateText.setText(rating);
                                txtBalance.setText("$"+resp.getUserDetail().getReferralBalance());
                                edtLocation.setText(location);
                                edtEmail.setText(email);
                                edtPhone.setText(mobilenumber);
                                edtId.setText(idproof);
                            }

                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobilenumber)) {
                                edtPhone.setHint("Phone Number");
                            }
                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(location)) {
                                edtLocation.setHint("Location");
                            }
                            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(idimage)) {
                                edtId.setHint("ID Verified (passport)");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProfileDetails> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your string won't be having lastname then this statement will cause error even before you can check for null.

`lastname = splitstring[1].trim();`

Try directly checking if `size()` of your array is larger than index you are accessing. If the size is larger then do your initializing for lastname.

Comment: you can just use `splitstring.size() >= 2` in if statement, if its true try getting lastname else don't.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use

```
if(textName.getText().toString().trim().contains(" ")){
     splitstring = txtName.split(" ");
   if (splitstring.length>1) {
      firstname = splitstring[0].trim();
      lastname = splitstring[1].trim();
 }
}else{
   Log.e("Name Error","Enter first and last Name")
}
```

Comment: What should i code in else part?because lastname takes the previous value

Comment: you can remove it i just added it for show error , you can warn user to enter name

Comment: When i call the update api without lastname, it takes the previous lastname as default

Comment: in this code it is already checking for extra space between name, at least one space is required otherwise it shows error and after space it will split string

Comment: you can use this easily

Comment: Yes i can understand, but how will i pass space as key for lastname in case user removed lastname during update?Now when i use this code lastname is passed as null.

Comment: how can user remove last name during update, if he will remove after api call api will put last data that you have enterd and if he will update again it will again check condition.

Comment: I have added my profile view api above. please check .